# Many to many relation on the same table

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, entity-relationship

I'm trying to setup a m2m relation between 'Gabarits'.

- One gabarit can have many Gabarits ( called Options )
- One gabarit can come from many Gabarits ( called OptionsFrom )

Here is my schema.yml:

```
Gabarit:
  actAs: [Attachable]
  columns:
    libelle: { type: string, size: 255 }
    description: { type: clob }
  relations:
    Options:
      class: Gabarit
      refClass: Gabarit2Gabarit
      local: gabarit_id
      foreign: fils_id
      foreignAlias: OptionsFrom

Gabarit2Gabarit:
  columns:
    fils_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    gabarit_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Gabarit:
      class: Gabarit
      local: gabarit_id
      alias: Gabarit
      foreignAlias: Gabarit2Gabarits
    Fils:
      class: Gabarit
      local: fils_id
      alias: Fils
      foreignAlias: Gabarit2Gabarits
```

Generated code is:

```
   $this->hasMany('Gabarit as Options', array(
         'refClass' => 'Gabarit2Gabarit',
         'local' => 'gabarit_id',
         'foreign' => 'fils_id'));

    $this->hasMany('Gabarit as OptionsFrom', array(
         'refClass' => 'Gabarit2Gabarit',
         'local' => 'fils_id',
         'foreign' => 'gabarit_id'));
```

It seems good, according to http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#relationships:join-table-associations:self-referencing-nest-relations:non-equal-nest-relations

Logically, it would give me this:

```
foreach($gabarit_>getOptions() as $option)
{
    in_array($gabarit->getId(), $options->getOptionsFrom()->getPrimaryKeys()); // should be true but returns false !!
}
```

Generated SQL for getOptions() :

```
SELECT gabarit.id AS gabarit__id, gabarit.libelle AS gabarit__libelle, gabarit.description AS gabarit__description, gabarit2_gabarit.fils_id AS gabarit2_gabarit__fils_id, gabarit2_gabarit.gabarit_id AS gabarit2_gabarit__gabarit_id FROM gabarit INNER JOIN gabarit2_gabarit ON gabarit.id = gabarit2_gabarit.fils_id WHERE gabarit.id IN (SELECT fils_id FROM gabarit2_gabarit WHERE gabarit_id = '507') ORDER BY gabarit.id ASC
```

Generated SQL for getOptionsFrom() :

```
SELECT gabarit.id AS gabarit__id, gabarit.libelle AS gabarit__libelle, gabarit.description AS gabarit__description, gabarit2_gabarit.fils_id AS gabarit2_gabarit__fils_id, gabarit2_gabarit.gabarit_id AS gabarit2_gabarit__gabarit_id FROM gabarit INNER JOIN gabarit2_gabarit ON gabarit.id = gabarit2_gabarit.gabarit_id WHERE gabarit.id IN (SELECT gabarit_id FROM gabarit2_gabarit WHERE fils_id = '529') ORDER BY gabarit.id ASC
```

Do you have any idea why Gabarit::getOptionsFrom returns an empty collection ?

thanks in advance,
Florian.

Comment: Are you missing the primary key from `Gabarit`? There are `description` and `libelle` but no defined primary key.

Comment: Hi, when ommiting the primary key, doctrine generates it automatically.

So my Gabarit has a id BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT ( mysql )

I think problem is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will most probably be the fact that you are using the same alias

foreignAlias: Gabarit2Gabarits

Your Gabarit2Gabarit should be like this:

```
Gabarit2Gabarit:
  columns:
    fils_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    gabarit_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
  relations:
    Gabarit:
      class: Gabarit
      local: gabarit_id
      alias: Gabarit
      foreignAlias: Gabarit2GabaritsGabarit
    Fils:
      class: Gabarit
      local: fils_id
      alias: Fils
      foreignAlias: Gabarit2GabaritsFils
```

That might help?

Comment: Amazing !!!! It works ! :)

Thank you very much, even if it seems logic now, I think I wouldn't have thought about it...

Thanks!
Florian.